# resource question sub-site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

There are many general resource questions that ask questions such as "what is the best programming language?" or "How do I implement this commonly-confusing thing?", which get closed for being subjective or generalized.  While these are currently outside the scope of SE, many have generated [intense community interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python).  Therefore, I suggest that instead of closing these questions, the best ones should be relocated to a new sister site like this:

> assorted.stackoverflow.com (or any other prefix)

I've looked around and seen something like this suggested before, but what I found suggested things such as a compiled FAQ or separate site (which is similar, but then would be hard to search since all site questions would be merged into one long list).

Of course, I understand the implications of such a heady statement, and the effort that would be required to accomplish this must be immense.  However there are good reasons for this change:

1. This would provide a place to ask subjective questions, which means instead of closing questions against the community's will, misplaced questions can be migrated.
2. This can discourage repetitious questions that continuously ask the same popular questions.  It certainly wouldn't get all of the duplicates, but it might help.
3. This would encourage users to write new, useful questions that are inherently subjective,  but are still very helpful.

A number of technologies could accompany this that could make integration simpler:

1. Each site has the sub-site in the main toolbar listed between "chat" and "main/meta".  This allows for quick navigation between the sub-sites.
2. The new sub-site could have its search results automatically included in the "main" portion of the site so that it can be seen by people posting their questions on the main page (to help avoid duplicates).
3. Either a new rating system could be imposed which does not affect the user's rep (i.e. is local to the question only) so that the questions can be ordered by rating, or rating can be taken out altogether.  I don't recommend tying in the rating with the parent site because the sites may become indistinguishable.
4. Allow for migration to the new sub-site.  Perhaps require less migration votes to move to this particular sub-site because A) it still pertains to the actual subject matter, and B) Migration would be more frequent to this sub-site.

Finally, if this would become a reality, Stack Exchange would likely require a change to their mission statement to include that there is a small subsection devoted to the most *highly-valued* subjective questions, or something along those lines.  Now, nothing ever gets done without first being discussed, so **how does everybody feel about all of this?**

**NOTE TO DOWNVOTERS**
Thank you for your interest.  Downvoting does not mean that you dislike my post.  Do **not** downvote because the question happens to be a duplicate of a question that by all means, I would never have found without stumbling across it myself (yes, I took a good hard look before I asked this one).  Remember that downvoting is only meant to indicate *a bad question* or for feature requests, a *poorly thought-out request*.  I took a lot of time writing this request; because you do not agree with it is no cause for the (to quote another user) "Haterade".

Comment: "closing questions against the community's will, "... it's mostly the community that closes questions.

Comment: They are closed because they do not fit the scope of the site, not because the community sees no value in them!  The community is what __votes them up__, remember.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> There are many general resource questions that ask questions such as **"what is the best programming language?"** or **"How do I implement this commonly-confusing thing?"**, which get closed for being subjective or generalized. While these are currently outside the scope of SE, many have generated intense community interest. Therefore, **I suggest that instead of closing these questions, the best ones should be relocated to a new sister site** like this:

I would be very interested to see what sort of "How can I implement this commonly-confusing thing?" question would actually get closed. "Generalised" isn't a reason for closing a question. I'll skip this part.

On the other hand, "What is the best programming language?" questions - and subjective questions in general - are generally closed because **they don't fit in the Q&A format.** There are several blog posts on why we don't allow certain kinds of subjective questions:

- [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)
- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) (there are actually *good* kinds of subjective questions)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Since bad subjective questions don't fit into the Q&A format - at all - these won't be saved by simply creating a sister Q&A site to ask them in. The solution is to **not ask them on a Q&A site.**

If you want to ask subjective questions that don't fit our format, **ask them in a site that doesn't use this format.** Ask about the best programming language on a forum that takes them, or in a chat room somewhere, or anywhere that supports these kinds of discussions or subjective questions. They can receive their community interest elsewhere.

Comment: "They don't fit in the Q&A format"... isn't that why I said that SE would have to edit their mission statement?  Of course they don't fit in the current scope of Stack Exchange.  _There is something missing in this type of community_, otherwise the community would not vote up the subjective questions so much.  I'm suggesting that to remedy this, the best subjective questions can be kept in a separate section (sub-site), so that instead of being closed, the community can continue to improve upon the answers.  Not all subjective questions are bad; SE should accommodate for them.

Comment: Here is what generalized looks like (from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question) "Too broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for a Q&A format. The question may be reopened if it is edited to focus on an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: "Not all subjective questions are bad; SE should accommodate for them." - The reason why they're called 'bad subjective', and the reason we don't, is because they're not a fit for **the format** of Stack Exchange. They're not bad universally, they just don't work here. It's got nothing to do with the Stack Exchange mission statement. The community and staff together just found, over several years, what kinds of questions work well in this Q&A engine and which are problematic.

Comment: SE has no more obligation to accommodate them than a chat room has an obligation to provide a full Q&A system. SE is a Q&A community and Q&A engine. It is a specialised tool made for a certain purpose, and breaks down when people use it for things other than that purpose (discussion questions, for instance). _There are other places_ for those other topics. If you want to have music and make toast, you use a music player and a toaster, instead of using one and complaining it doesn't also make toast / play music. That's a wacky example, but it's the same thing here - find a different tool.

Comment: No, Stack Exchange does not need to provide for them, but it would be beneficial.  That is the whole point of this topic; to suggest a possible feature and see if other users felt the same way.  Sorry to have asked.

Comment: I wasn't one of the ones who downvoted you, though I couldn't do much about others doing so. I would prefer you weren't sorry to have asked!